# StreamWriter doesn't work

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I dont know why it isn't working but ths is where it fails:

```
        outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + @"\conn.txt", append: false);
        outputFile.Write(connections);
        outputFile.Close();
```

I would like any help. I am stuck hier for quiet some time.

Comment: Can you describe 'doesn't work' for us?

Comment: FYI easier to `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "conn.txt"), connections);`

Comment: Why does nobody ever use `Path.Combine()`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: Thx 4 the help but it works with the answer of Simon. But Path.Combine() is alsow nice to know thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + @"\conn.txt", append: false);
```

but I recommend to you to try this:

```
outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + @"\conn.txt");
```

witheout the "append: false" part.

Comment: I will try hope it works.